# inputs de diferente ancho en Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente código en Bootstrap:

```html
<form action="contactoGracias.html">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-50" id="name" required>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="surname">Apellidos:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control w-50" id="surname" required>
 </div>
</form>
```

Si no pongo nada más los inputs me ocupan el 100% del elemento padre.
¿Existe alguna clase que especifique que quiero que ocupen el 100% cuando el tamaño de pantalla es pequeña y que ocupe el 50% cuando el tamaño de pantalla es grande?
Gracias

Comment: en la documentación de boostrap está toda la info que necesitas, para eso se usan media queries o break points
Podes investigar más aca
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque ya tengas una respuesta aceptada (o comentario...), no precisamente necesitas `@media queries`, pues éstas ya están en las clases del grid de Bootstrap.

Una de ellas, poco conocida, es [`.form-row`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#form-row), disponible desde la versión `4.0.0`. Gracias a las siguientes propiedades,

```
display: flex; 
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-right: -5px;
margin-left: -5px;
```

Puedes crear formularios, más o menos complejos, o por lo menos, te permite hacer lo que necesitas usando la grilla. Todo depende de cómo quieras jugar.

Sabiendo esto, basta con usar las clásicas clases para columnas, `.col-sm-12` (para que esos `inputs` ocupen todo el ancho en resoluciones pequeñas) y `.col-md-6` (para que ocupen el 50% del ancho en las siguientes resoluciones).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form action="contactoGracias.html">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <label for="surname">Apellidos:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifica tu css de la siguiente manera

```
/* Desktops grandes y tabletas grandes */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
 .form-group {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
}

input[type='text'] {
    width: 50%;
}
}

/* Mayoria de los telefonos */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .form-group {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
}

input[type='text'] {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```